# Entity Framework DbExecutionStrategy doesn't work without setting Database.CommandTimeout

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In have a CustomDbConfiguration class based on DbConfiguration:

```
internal class CustomDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
```

The constructor sets the execution strategy and an interceptor is used to generate a transient failure:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomDBConfiguration()
    {
        // Add transient failure.
        AddInterceptor(new TransientFailure());  // <-- Used to create a transient failure.

        // Set the execution strategy.
        SetExecutionStrategy
            (SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
            () => new MyDBExecutionStrategy(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
    }
```

MyDBExecutionStrategy is based on DbExecutionStrategy:

```
internal class MyDBExecutionStrategy : DbExecutionStrategy
```

And implements the ShouldRetryOn Boolean when an error occurs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retry on error?
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception ex)
```

However, when I instantiate my DbContext, if I don't include the line "_context.Database.CommandTimeout = 1;" then the execution strategy is not used:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test by getting a list of people.
    /// </summary>
    private void TryItOut()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a new Context instance, with a connection string specified.
                _context = new MyDBContext(_connectionString);

                // --- IF I TEXT THIS LINE OUT THEN THE EXECUTION STRATEGY ISN'T IMPLEMENTED ---
                _context.Database.CommandTimeout = 1;  

                List<Person> people = _context.People.ToList();

                MessageBox.Show("People count: " + people.Count());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }            
    }
```

The line indicated seems to me to be redundant, but if it is not present then the strategy is not called.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `TransientFailure` class?

Comment: The TransientFailure class is just something I put together to introduce a transient failure - it is based on the interface IDbCommandInterceptor.  I didn't include the details here because it isn't relevant to the main problem.  Just a tool for creating an error.  Thanks.